# Unsequenced modification warning becomes result unused warning in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, sequence

I'm experimenting with [this](https://github.com/vinniefalco/DSPFilters) filters library, and getting an unsequenced modification warning from the following snippet.

```
while (--numSamples >= 0)
    *dest++ = state.process(*dest, *this);
```

This makes sense looking at similar questions on SO, as dest is being modified and accessed in the same command. So, I guess the intended functionality is the following . . .

```
while (--numSamples >= 0) {
    *dest = state.process(*dest, *this);
    *dest++;
}
```

However, this gives a new, more curious warning "warning: expression result unused" for the post increment. Why this new warning, and how should I fix this correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*dest++` increments `dest`, and dereferences the prior value of `dest`. The increment is a side effect that you want, the dereference has no effect. Just write it as `dest++` (or `++dest`).

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm pretty sure based on the code in the question that the intent really is to increment `dest`.

Comment: @hvd just had a total derp moment. Thanks